# How To Add References Permanently for Crystal Reports in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

> Everytime I create a new WinForms project and try using Crystal Reports in it, I have to follow the below mentioned steps time and again. Suggest a solution to add the below mentioned references permanently to my VS 2010.

.NET Framework 4.0 instead of .NET Framework 4.0 Client in the application properties.

Have added a reference CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 1):

```
1:- Setup Crystal report 
2:- go to  project and right click (Add References )
3:- Browse For Crystal Report in Program Files  
4:- Add The References
5:- Right click in references and copy Local set True
```

Comment: I am using VS 2010 and I have installed crystal reports after installing visual studio, where can I now find crystal reports as they are not there in program files as you had mentioned. Please help.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet

Comment: sorry for a late reply, the steps that you have mentioned are not complete.

Comment: I have to do the above mentioned 2 changes in the VS 2010 and also make some changes in the app.config file. You can read my prior questions and their answers to get a better insight. If that helps, vote me up.